# xcode4 file not found when is already in project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, import

I'm using touch JSON, I imported and copied the files inside my folder,

then `#import "CJSONDeserializer.h"` which is recognized by the autocompleter, but when building, it appears that `CJSONDeserializer file not found`

So what am I doing wrong while importing, or how to make it recognize the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that you have not added the header files to your target. To do so go to your project navigator top level, select it, select target, and go to the "search paths" sections, then in the header search path add the path to the CJSONDeserializer.h relative to where your .xcodeproject is.

Comment: For others having this issue, if you use submodules also check that the dropdown right of Target Membership is set to Public not Project

Answer (score 1):

Where did you place the imported files? make sure you **copy** the files to the project and not just **reference** them. Also, go to Build Settings in xcode when clicking the main project, try to edit the option **Header Search Paths** with the path of the imported files

Answer (score 1):

While copying file have checked the box asking for copy to this folder. If yes then delete and try again. This issue has encountered several times while importing file or copying.